# Marker not centering in iframe for google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, iframe

I have bit strange requirement of open google map in iframe. i have address that i use to pass and convert that into google map. but the trouble is the size of my iframe is 200*200 so the marker is not getting centered. and the other problem is the marker infowindow also gets poppedup after few seconds that makes my marker out of the frame boundry.and marker moves from the centere.
my code is like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#map_address").each(function(){   
    var embed ='<iframe class="map_google" width="200" scrolling="no" height="200" frameborder="0" src="https:/maps.google.com/maps?&q=Ahmedabad&output=embed" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">';
    $(this).html(embed);
  });
});
```

i want to close the marker info window and make the marker cenetered. any help will be appreciated.

this was created by the use of the 
http://jsbin.com/welcome/68407/edit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add an `iwloc`-parameter without a value to the iframe-URL: http://jsbin.com/emoyup/1/edit

Description of URL-parameters: http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

Comment: thanx dude....perfact...though i changed the whole code now i will use this...little late but perfact...

Comment: I used this for about a day before I started getting this error: "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Unexpected parameter 'iwloc'."