# Google Maps iframe not showing dropped pins centered

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add two maps to my website, each with two drop pins. Users can switch between the two maps by clicking on tabs. I built the two maps using the Google Maps Engine. The first map appears great, zoomed in to the right amount and showing the two pins. However, the second map is totally off. I tried doing what was suggested in this previous question [Marker not centering in iframe for google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076633/marker-not-centering-in-iframe-for-google-map) but 1) it was still off and 2) I was unable to add a second pin to the map (plus the map did not look as nice as the iframe I embedded directly on to the site).

Here is the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SbH3Y/5/

Google Maps iframes:

```
<iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zzFoZgN4yc_E.kT_V1HoEUMHs" width="461" height="350" scrolling='no'  marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'></iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reload the iframe in the 2nd tab when it gets selected. The best would be when you initially have an empty iframe and set the `src` at the first time the tab will be selected.

simple reloading of the frame would be easy:

```
  $('#pickup-date2').show(0,function(){         
    $('iframe',this)
      .attr('src','http://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zzFoZgN4yc_E.kT_V1HoEUMHs');
  });
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jUVuB/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jUVuB/)

But this would reload the iframe each time you select the tab.
**Better approach:**

the iframe:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" 
        data-src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zzFoZgN4yc_E.kT_V1HoEUMHs" 
        width="461" height="350"></iframe>
```

As you see the map initially will not be loaded, the `src` is blank and the URL of the map is stored in the `data-src`-attribute

the script:

```
  $('#pickup-date2')
   .show(0,function(){
      //when the iframe has data-src
      if($('iframe',this).data('src')){
        $('iframe',this)
          //set the src-attribute
          .attr('src',$('iframe',this).data('src'))
            //and set data-src to null,
            //so the iframe will only be reloaded on the first click
            .data('src',null);
      } });
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/tWCUR/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/tWCUR/)

Comment: this was awesome, it worked brilliantly and your fiddle made it easy to implement. Thank you

Comment: This answer is life saving. Thanks a lot. After 2 days hard work, this answer saves me.

Comment: I had to modify this a tiny bit to make it work with my specific design and requirements, but this saved me for sure.  A reminder, as I am using Magento - it's best to install the jquery module when using Magento, and you won't be using $ - You'll likely use jQuery instead. For example jQuery(document).ready(function () {}