# Embedded Google Map iframe not Centering Marker

Tags: html, google-maps

I have the following bit of code I am using in order to show a map on my website:

```
        <div class="embed-container maps">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d18730122.383938454!2d-7.362368!3d55.03634899999871!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x485fe22e4b6ff5d7%3A0xf32e6f9c480d1e1c!2sDee.ie+Ltd!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1409609045175" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
        </div>
```

The problem is, the marker is way off to the left and is not centered. Does this have something to do with the width being 100%? If so, how do I correct this?

EDIT:

What I noticed, is I have 2 monitors hooked up, could this be trying to center the map between both monitors?? It is technically perfectly centered if I look at it from that point of view.

Comment: You can try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076633/marker-not-centering-in-iframe-for-google-map .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by using the following jQuery:

> $('.maps iframe').css('width', $(window).width()+'px');